# How to check a 2D array diagonally?

Tags: c++, arrays

I do have an 2D array and I want to check it diagonally for a number that repeats itself 5 times and is not zero. I do have it working from left to right but it wont work from right to left. Could you please help me ?
Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m_len - 5 ;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= m_len - 5 ;j++)
        {
            if (m_boardRows[i][j]!=0 &&
            m_boardRows[i][j]==m_boardRows[i+1][j+1] &&
            m_boardRows[i][j]==m_boardRows[i+2][j+2] &&
            m_boardRows[i][j]==m_boardRows[i+3][j+3] &&
            m_boardRows[i][j]==m_boardRows[i+4][j+4])
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (m_boardRows[m_len-1-i][m_len-1-j]!=0 &&
            m_boardRows[m_len-1-i][m_len-1-j]==m_boardRows[m_len-1-i-1][m_len-1-j-1] &&
            m_boardRows[m_len-1-i][m_len-1-j]==m_boardRows[m_len-1-i-2][m_len-1-j-2] &&
            m_boardRows[m_len-1-i][m_len-1-j]==m_boardRows[m_len-1-i-3][m_len-1-j-3] &&
            m_boardRows[m_len-1-i][m_len-1-j]==m_boardRows[m_len-1-i-4][m_len-1-j-4])
        {
            return true;
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from right to left you just have to do a for loop that looks like

```
for (i = m_len - 5; i >= 0; i--){}
```

Comment: well yeah but I do already have one loop that checks it also vertically and horizontally, so I would like to merge it together

Comment: Then just check at m_boardRows[m_len - 5 - i][j]

Comment: Are you trying to check from bottom to top on  your right to left?

Comment: then your `[m_len-1-j-1]` and following j indexes should be the same as the first `if` statement `[j+1]`.

Comment: oh yes I havent thought of that - thanks, ill try it